# Running mongod in shell works but it does not work as a service

Tags: linux, mongodb, service

I am running mongod under Linux OS. I wanted to change my data directory from the default `/var/lib/mongodb` to another location say `/nfs/mongodb`.

When I run mongodb from shell(i.e. sudo /usr/bin/mongod --dbpath /nfs/mongodb) It works just fine.

Next step, I tried to run mongodb as a service(`sudo service mongodb start`)

I modified the file `/etc/mongodb.conf` and changed the line `dppath=xxx` to point to the new directory I created. When I run mongodb as service I get this error:

```
couldn't open file /nfs/mongodb/journal/j._0 for writing errno:1 Operation not permitted, terminating
```

Why the mongodb works in the shell and not as a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very likely because of permission issue.

When you run `sudo mongod`, it runs as root and can write to any directory.

In contrast, when running as a service, MongoDB typically runs as a limited-privilege user to prevent any security issue to escalate to root level access.

The solution is to `chmod` or `chown` the intended `dbpath` directory so that it's writeable by the service's user.

**Note**: you may want to check out the [Production Notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/) for tips on running MongoDB optimally.

Comment: I am using a network share drive /nfs for my mongodb storage. I can not change the ownership of the directory. Is there is a way to run mongodb as a daemon mode and start and stop it with simple scripts?

Comment: @motam79 although it's possible to run MongoDB on a networked drive, it's usually not a recommended practice due to performance and permission issues you're facing. MongoDB only provides the server binaries, so if you require other features to start/stop the server, you would need to consult your OS on how to do that.